# Do I need a fully synced Mist wallet in order to deploy a contract?

Tags: wallets, mist, contract-deployment

The syncing takes ages and I'm wondering if it's possible to deploy a smartcontract in Mist while its not fully synced. [image: my current status]

Comment: No, I still want to deploy it on Mist

Comment: The linked question answer your question: it is not possible to deploy a contract without a fully synchronized node. If you insist on using Mist you can try with launching geth in "light" mode, but I've never tested it to deploy a contract.